# Filter from patterns in file

Tags: shell, csv

I got two csv files, with the following formats:

```
BigFile.csv:

11111,,101010
22222,xxxxxx,202020
33333,yyyyyy,303030
44444,,404040

LittleFile.csv:

xxxxxx
yyyyyy
wwwwww
zzzzzz
```

I need to create a new .csv file that contains every `BigFile.csv` line that contains a `LittleFile.csv` value in the second column, like:

```
NewFile.csv

22222,xxxxxx,202020
33333,yyyyyy,303030
```

Comment: And how do you want to do it? With a Shell-Script?

Comment: Yes!!! I can manipulate a file with cats and greps, but I'm new to it and can't compare different files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {value[$1]; next} $2 in value' little big > new
```

An awk script is a sequence of `condition {action}` pairs. If the condition evaluates to "true" the action block is executed. If the condition is missing, it is implicitly true and the action is performed for every record. If the action is missing, it implicitly prints the current record: `{print $0}`

While awk is reading records from files or from stdin, it keeps track of how many records it has read in total. This is stored in the `NR` variable.

If awk is reading from multiple files, it keeps track of the record number of the current file. This is stored in the `FNR` variable. When awk reads the *first record* from the *second file*, NR will be one plus the number of records in the first file, and FNR will be one.

`NR == FNR` is an awk idiom: the total number of records (NR) will only be equal to the record number of the current file (FNR) if awk is processing the **first** file in the list. This is how we can read the contents of the "little" file into an array, and then use that array when processing the second file "big".

Note that I'm specifically saying "record" instead of "line" -- the default record separator is newline, so a record *is* a line, but we can redefine the record separator to read multiple lines or even only part of a line, and consider that as a complete record.

Comment: Can you please explain what the NR==FMR does?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the -f option of grep :

```
grep BigFile.csv -f LittleFile.csv > result.csv
```

## man grep

> Matching Control
>
> ```
> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>         Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it does not restrict the match to the 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

Try the unix "join" command.  Something like:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -t, BigFile.csv LittleFile.csv
```

should do it.